# If I activate some query Firebase adapter part does not work even though others work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase adpater part does not work. so my recyclerview does not show . i am trying to make divide pages by using firebasedatabase. if i click button 1, it has to show 1~3posts. button2 , it has to show 4~6posts and so on...

i tried a lot of things ... try adding tag . i find it gets needed data from other functions. and go to fetch function for activating my query. but it does not play adapter part in fetch method.

```
 private void awesomeButtonClicked(final MyCallback2 myCallback) {

    if (left == 0) {
        if(listcallback3!=null) {
            databaseReference3 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts");
            query2 = databaseReference3.orderByChild("date2").startAt((listcallback3.get(3*hint))).endAt(listcallback3.get((hint * 3)+2) );
            Log.d("bbb", "" + hint);
            fetch(query2);
            Log.d("bbb", "" + hint);
        }
        databaseReference.orderByChild("date2").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                 Long eventID = ds.child("date2").getValue(Long.class);
                 list.add(eventID);
                 myCallback.onCallback(list);

                     }

             }



            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }

    else {

        if(listcallback3!=null) {
            Log.d("tagtagggg", "" + hint);
            databaseReference4 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts");
            query3 = databaseReference4.orderByChild("date2").startAt((listcallback3.get(hint*3))).endAt(listcallback3.get((hint * 3)+2) );


            fetch(query3);

        }
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                list = new ArrayList<>();
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    eventID = ds.child("date2").getValue(Long.class);

                    list.add(eventID);
                    myCallback.onCallback(list);
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


    }
}




                private void fetch (Query query){

                    Log.d("fragment_two", "10" + query);
                    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Post> options =
                            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
                                    .setQuery(query, Post.class)
                                    .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                                    .build();

                    Log.d("fragment_two", "11" + options);

                    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, ViewHolder>(options) {
                        @Override
                        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                            Log.d("fragment_two", "19");
                            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                            Log.d("fragment_two", "19");
                            // String.valueOf(adapter.getItemCount());
                            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
                            Log.d("fragment_two", "19");

                            return holder;


                        }
```

click button , i want to get data . but adapter part does not work at all. other queries work fine. according to tags , adater works well. but
awesomebuttonclicked method does not make  'Log.d("fragment_two", "19");' work

Answer (score 0):

i fount the answer . 
it was the problem of type.
i put the long type startat(), endat()
because i have to use timestamp 
it seems firebase startat() does not accept long number like 123456789123456789.
so i changed the long type to the string type.